# Plot year below month on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not looking for help with coding, just a help in what direction I should take, i.e. what functions to use. I wonder if it is possible to use ggplot to plot something of like of this:

[image]

Comment: Facets. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-row x-axis labels in ggplot line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/multi-row-x-axis-labels-in-ggplot-line-chart)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49092859/786542

Comment: @Tyler Upton: Could you guide me to what you mean in that link that will help me? I see now multivariable x-asis there

Comment: @Tung: Thanks! that looks like multiple plots, not one, or?

Comment: @LAP: thank you, that might look like something that could work for me. I could just switch Q1, Q2... etc with dates right?

Comment: Sure, you just need one `year` variable and another (day, week, month, quarter, whatever) for the `interaction`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1)** One easy way is place the year under each January (or use June, say, if you want the year centered -- i.e. replace 1 with 6 in the code below).  Another approach is to just replace January with the year by using `%Y` in place of `%b\n%Y`.

First introduce some test data -- this should normally be done in the question but I have provided some this time.  The `x` column of the test data frame `d` is of class `"yearmon"` and `y` is numeric.  I have assumed that the numbers on the X axis in the question were intended to represent months but if they were intended to be quarters then start off with `"yearqtr"` class and use `scale_x_yearqtr` instead adjusting appropriately.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

d <- data.frame(x = as.yearmon("2000-1") + 0:23/12, y = 1:24) # test data

x <- d$x
autoplot(d) 
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_yearmon(breaks = x, lab = format(x, ifelse(cycle(x) == 1, "%b\n%Y", "%b")))
```

**2)** or if you are starting off with a zoo object `z`:

```
z <- read.zoo(d)
x <- time(z)
autoplot(z, geom = c("line", "point")) + 
  scale_x_yearmon(breaks = x, lab = format(x, ifelse(cycle(x) == 1, "%b\n%Y", "%b"))) + 
  xlab("")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Fantatic idea, I love it!

Comment: What is `autoplot` here?

Comment: The `x <- d$x` is really confusing