# Image footnotes in Bookdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

How can I add a figure note right below the image in `bookdown::pdf_document2`? It is relatively easy to do for plots that created by `ggplot2`. `grid.arrange` can do the work with `grid.arrange(<plot>, bottom = <figure_notes>)`. But if I insert an image manually, e.g., `knitr::include_graphics(rep("images/knit-logo.png", 3))`, is there a way to add a figure note to it? I saw a `knitr` option, `fig.subcap`. But this fails to compile:

````
```{r fig.show="hold", fig.cap = "a", fig.subcap = "b"}

knitr::include_graphics(rep("images/knit-logo.png", 3))

```
````

This returns:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \subfloat 

Error: Failed to compile miniSample.tex. See miniSample.log for more info.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an expedient solution:

1. Read the image into R using `magick::image_read`;
2. Convert the image to `raster` project with `rasterGrob`;
3. Create a note with `textGrob`; Use `grid.arrange` to present;
4. Present the image together with note using `grid.arrange`.

   `plot_A <- magick::image_read(<path>) %>% rasterGrob(interpolate = TRUE)
   note <- textGrob("This is a note.")
   grid.arrange(plot_A, bottom = note)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use subfigures, you have to load the `subfig` package within LaTeX. This can be done by using the `header-includes` argument in the YAML, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown).

Here is a minimal, reproducible example, It creates a local image "temp.jpg" and then produces three subfigures:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{subfig}
---

```{r}
jpeg(filename = "temp.jpg")
plot(cars)
dev.off()
```

```{r fig.show="hold", fig.cap = "a", fig.subcap = c("Your Caption", "Another Caption", "Isn't this great"), fig.ncol = 3, out.width="33%"}
knitr::include_graphics(rep("temp.jpg", 3))
```
````

[image]

> Check out this post for the original description: [Subfigures or Subcaptions with knitr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546365/subfigures-or-subcaptions-with-knitr)