# Numbering figures of plot(glm) in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, figures

I created a `Rmarkdown` document and want to number my figures. What I am struggling with is if a `plot` gives me several output like `plot("glm Object")`?

Here is a minimal example:

````
---
documentclass: article
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'figures/', fig.pos = 'htb!', echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, fig.cap = "Test"}
data(warpbreaks)
daten <- as.data.frame(warpbreaks)
test <- glm(breaks ~ tension + wool , family = "poisson", data = daten)
plot(test)
```
````

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. Are you wanting to add a figure caption to the plots?

Comment: Yes, to each Plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lesser-known feature of Rmarkdown and add captions to subfigures: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086985/7347699

For your example:

````
---
documentclass: article
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{subfig}
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'figures/', fig.pos = 'htb!', echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, fig.cap = "Test",  fig.subcap=c('sub 1', 'sub 2', 'sub 3', 'sub 4'), out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.asp=1, fig.ncol = 2}
data(warpbreaks)
daten <- as.data.frame(warpbreaks)
test <- glm(breaks ~ tension + wool , family = "poisson", data = daten)
plot(test)
```
````

[image]

### Alternative Approach

A potentially easier way plotting multiple R plots is to use the `par` function before plotting. The benefit of this is its simplicity, and that you do not need to load addition LaTeX packages in the header. However, it is not possible to add a sub-caption to each plot.

````
---
documentclass: article
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, fig.cap = "Test", fig.asp = 1}
data(warpbreaks)
daten <- as.data.frame(warpbreaks)
test <- glm(breaks ~ tension + wool , family = "poisson", data = daten)

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(test)
```
````

[image]

Comment: i tried your code but dont get the same result as you, please check my edit

Comment: It looks like you haven't got the settings right in the code chunk. As you haven't supplied the code, it is  You want to make sure that the subfigure captions are in here: `fig.subcap=c('sub 1', 'sub 2', 'sub 3', 'sub 4'), out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.asp=1, fig.ncol = 2`. Also looks like you have changed `fig.ncol` to 4.

Comment: I removed the edit. It doesn't relate to the code posted in the question so makes things confusing. Here is a link to your figure though: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yO7V.png

Comment: it still doesnt work, mabye the reason is because i have text before and after the chunk?

Comment: You seem to be combining the plots into pairs? P.S. As your first post, I am happy to help out a bit. But generally speaking, it is not for those to answer to troubleshoot the code when you try and implement it yourself. If you discover another question separate to the original one, it can often be better to start a new question

Comment: no i just create a plot function that give me the four plots i posted. And now i want to have the same layout like in your answer but i allways get my plots in a rown and don't  2 rows with 2 plots  like you. I think i will post a new question

Comment: Okay, that sounds strange. Without looking at your code it is impossible to diagnose. Worth making another question, and please make sure it is fully reproducible. Post the link here so that I can help answer it :) Also would appreciate if you could upvote my answer :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395974/place-figures-right-in-r-markdown   here is the new question . i cant upvote because this account is new. dont enough reputations sry