# Issues plotting multiple plots in a single figure within RMarkdown

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, figure

I have plot function that produce four plots like glm. A histogramm, a boxplot and two scatterplots. But I cant put them in the right place in my document so that I can see all informations. I want 2 plots in 1 row and to be wide so I can see all informations like header etc.

It's senseless to post my plot function, because it's for a class that I created.

My output looks always like this
[image]

I have the following YAML layout:

````
---
title: 
author:
fontsize: 11
graphics: true
documentclass: article
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: true
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    toc_depth: 2
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{subfig}
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'figures/', fig.pos = 'htb!', echo = TRUE)
knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options)  {
  hook_plot_tex(x, options)
})
```

```{r, out.width='1\\linewidth', fig.asp=0.5, fig.ncol = 1, fig.cap="output",fig.align = "center"}
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(poisReg)
```
````

Comment: Always make sure your questions are reproducible. If you don't want to include your plot function, you should try and include something which replicates the behaviour. Could it be replaced with two `plot(cars)` lines?

Comment: no for two car plots i get the result that i want but not for my plots hmmm. maybe i should post my whole code but its so long..

Comment: You haven't followed the solution recommended previously either. There is no `fig.subcap`. Also, why are you mixing that with `par(mfrow = c(1, 2))`?

Comment: Also, please try and provide a minimal working example. With all the YAML, the knit_hooks, there are literally dozens of things which could be wrong. It makes answering more difficult. I know you are new to StackOverflow, so I am trying to help you get better so that it is easier for people to provide you with answers.

Comment: finally i fixed it. The problem was that i had to many figures in my figure folder. I dont know why but your solution didnt worked i used an other work arround. THanks for your time and help. Your a good man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am failing to replicate your problem. Using a reproducible set of plots:

````
---
title: 
author:
fontsize: 11
graphics: true
documentclass: article
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: true
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    toc_depth: 2
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{subfig}
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'figures/', fig.pos = 'htb!', echo = TRUE)
knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options)  {
  hook_plot_tex(x, options)
})
```

```{r, out.width='1\\linewidth', fig.asp=0.5, fig.ncol = 1, fig.cap="output",fig.align = "center"}
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(cars, main = "Title 1")
plot(cars, main = "Title 2")
plot(cars, main = "Title 3")
plot(cars, main = "Title 4")
```
````

[image]

It seems to me that something is being messed up the knitr setting up the `figures` folder.