# Rmarkdown: Multiple plots on same page with separate captions

Tags: r-markdown, gridextra

I am writing a report in R markdown with a pdf output. I have several plots and I would like to display four plots per page laid out in a 2x2 matrix. Is there a way to get them to display like that with separate captions?

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Package gridExtra -  I can easily setup the layout I want but I wasn't able to add captions to the plots.Is there an option to add captions to the plot in `grid.arrange`?
- Placing each plot in a different chunk and playing with R chunk options. Basically setting `out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.align='right'` and `fig.align='left'` alternatively. Here I can set individual captions with `fig.cap` but the plots always show up on separate pages.
- I tried playing with the `fig.width` and `fig.height` options and was able to get them to display on the same page on their respective left or right sides of the page. However the caption always takes the full page width and stays in center instead of wrapping with the plot size. Is there a way to make caption follow the plot sizing rules?

Here is a sample code:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results=FALSE, warning=FALSE,  comment=FALSE, message= FALSE, eval =T, fig.height= 9}

p1<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
labs(caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ")+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p2<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
labs(caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  ")+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p3<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
labs(caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ")+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p4<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
labs(caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ")+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```
````

[image: Here is the output image]
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: at the end of each ggplot you can add captions like this then use gridExtra -  `labs(caption = "Hi world")`

Comment: Thanks I tried that just now. It works except all the captions are on top of each other. Is there a way to neatly wrap the captions under the plot?

Comment: Can you share your code/data so I can see the issue?

Comment: If you are just trying to wrap the text in the caption you can do this `labs(caption = "Hi \nworld")` . the \n will put world on the second line

Comment: If you only want PDF output you can check out the use of sibfigure https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086985/7347699

Comment: @Mike I added a sample code and I tried adding \n but I have twenty plots and its just taking forever to edit each caption individually. I am surprised that its not more straight forward

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use subfigures within LaTeX Outputs, as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546365/subfigures-or-subcaptions-with-knitr/49086985#49086985). If you have lots of plots and you want to provide the captions easier, you can specify these in a list (i.e. `captions <- c("Caption 1", "Caption 2"`) before the chunk and the provide this list to the chunk as `fig.subcap=captions`

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{subfig}
---  

```{r}
captions <- c("Caption 1",
              "Caption 2", 
              "Caption 3",
              "Caption 4: a very very very very very very very very very long one")
```


```{r, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results=FALSE, warning=FALSE,  comment=FALSE, message= FALSE, eval =T,  fig.cap = "Overall Caption", fig.subcap=captions, out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.asp=1, fig.ncol = 2}
library(ggplot2)
p1<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p2<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p3<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p4<- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p1
p2
p3
p4
```
````

[image]

## Edit

To ensure there is margin between the subfigures, you can add the `margins` option when loading the package:

```
  - \usepackage[margin = 8pt]{subfig}
```

Check out the other options in the package documentation: http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf

Comment: Actually, some of my captions are really long and they don't quite overlap but they touch and are kinda hard to read. Is there an option to add space between the captions?

Comment: Yeah I did try that but it make all four plots smaller without altering the caption width