# Align Table and Plot In Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I want to place a table next to a plot (plot is based on the very table) and ideally visually align the table rows with the ticks of the plot. Currently I am playing with `theme(plot.margin)` and `fig.height` to try to do that by hand and results are OKish, but as soon as something changes (adding legends to the plot, or rows to the table) I have to re-iterate.

Are there any better approaches to achieve the same results in a more automated way? Maybe adding the table to the plot?

**Screenshots**

*With manual alignment*
[image: Aligned]

*Without manual alignment*
[image: Unaligned]

**Code**

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
                      message = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE,
                      fig.align = "center")
```

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-3">
```{r}
raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg)
kable(raw_dat) %>%
   kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"),
                 full_width = FALSE)
```
</div>
<div class = "col-md-9">
```{r, fig.height=5.5}
   ggplot(raw_dat, aes(factor(id, rev(id)), mpg)) +
   geom_point() +
   coord_flip() +
   theme(plot.margin = margin(0.6, unit = "cm"))
```
</div>
</div>
````

Comment: Does anything from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659160/r-markdown-positioning-table-and-plot-side-by-side) help?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But this post describe only how to put the table and the plot side by side (which I know how to do at least for the HTML output). However, I was wondering if there is a way how to align them row by tick, so to speak.

Comment: I see - you want to make the height the same for table and plot?

Comment: Not necessarily the height, but ideally the tick mark for `Mazda` for instance is exactly in the middle of the row of `Mazda`.