# How to get my table and graph in same row

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I am compiling a report in Rmarkdown in which I have a graph and a table that needs to be in the same row. Currently, I am not able to get them in the same row but the graph is above the table. I am providing my YAML and the codes from graph and table. The table output is in latex form and that is also creating problems. I'm thinking of converting my table into `.png` and attaching with with the graph but there should be a way of getting a latex table and graph aligned in Rmarkdown(Edit: please read the paragraph at the end):

````
---
title: Domestic and Global Price Trends – Key Commodities
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage{floatrow}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{1.5cm}
  \rhead{Research Department}
  \lhead{x} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}} 
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
options(scipen = 10)

```

```{r include=FALSE} 
ref=structure(list(date = structure(c(19236, 19243, 19250, 19257, 
19264, 19271, 19278, 19285, 19292, 19299, 19306, 19313, 19320, 
19327, 19334, 19341, 19348, 19355, 19362, 19369, 19376, 19383, 
19390, 19397, 19404, 19411, 19418, 19425, 19432, 19439, 19446, 
19453, 19460, 19467, 19474, 19481, 19488, 19495, 19502, 19509, 
19516, 19523, 19530, 19537, 19544, 19551, 19558, 19565, 19572, 
19579, 19586, 19593, 19600, 19607, 19614, 19621, 19628, 19635, 
19642, 19649, 19656), class = "Date"), SPI_WoW = c(1.31, -0.583352030513795, 
-0.19, -8.10798589129058, 0.944835391959042, 0.29, -0.573567296942579, 
0.35, 4.13, 0.533358285767749, 0.744601638123599, 0.62, 0.482049398586004, 
-0.16, 0, -0.402709134175372, -0.11, -0.09, 1.09, 0.44, 0.0045345304493738, 
0.453432483903149, 2.82116096415996, 0.17, 2.89258009378972, 
2.77718618222089, -0.29839612085043, 1.37, 0.963628162545627, 
1.8, -0.36, 0.92, -0.6, 0.506864623243941, 0.15, 1.05, 0.27, 
-0.16, -0.42, 0.03, 0.21, 0.2, 0.33, 0.33, 0.7, 0.33, -0.07, 
3.73, 1.3, 0.69, 0.78, 0.05, 0.54, 0.96, -0.25, 0.93, -0.02, 
0.11, 0.3, -1.70402319168493, -0.33), SPI_YoY = c(45.5, 42.6961226330027, 
40.58, 29.2766715439914, 30.6227712684666, 29.44, 28.4377747080246, 
27.13, 30.68, 30.6023217650276, 29.2417910447761, 28.67, 30.1558039961941, 
30.56, 30.66, 29.4243577545195, 28.76, 29.3, 30.3, 31.75, 31.8309522386275, 
32.5713601819161, 34.4925311448308, 34.83, 38.4175461352515, 
41.5439666803543, 41.071952149182, 42.27, 45.6406009700698, 46.65, 
45.36, 44.49, 44.61, 47.2259573224203, 46.82, 48.38, 48.02, 45.72, 
45.49, 42.67, 39.26, 34.96, 34.05, 34.05, 28.55, 28.96, 29.16, 
29.21, 29.83, 30.82, 27.57, 25.34, 24.39, 26.32, 26.25, 38.66, 
37.33, 37.07, 38.28, 35.4508695863984, 29.65)), row.names = c(NA, 
-61L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
SPI=structure(list(A = c("Tomatoes", "Pulse Masoor", "Sugar", "Diesel", 
"LPG"), B = c(17, 10.87, 6.73, 6.28, 5.19), C = c("Chicken", 
"Cooking oil", "Veg. Ghee (2.5kg)", "Tea", "Veg. Ghee (1kg)"), 
    D = c(-3.2, -1.03, -0.47, -0.43, -0.14)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

``` 

```{r plot1, echo=F ,out.width="50%",out.height="50%",fig.align='center' ,warning=F, message=F}
df<-tail(ref,n=52)
d=max(df$SPI_WoW)
c=min(df$SPI_WoW)
b=max(df$SPI_YoY)
a=min(df$SPI_YoY)
m=(d-c)/(b-a)
k=(c*b-a*d)/(b-a)
a=df%>% ggplot(aes(x=as.Date(date)))+geom_line(aes(y=SPI_WoW, color="SPI_WoW"),linewidth=1)+geom_line(aes(y=(m*SPI_YoY+k), color="SPI_YoY"),linewidth=1)+scale_y_continuous(name = "SPI_WoW",sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ (.-k)/m,name = "SPI_YoY"))+scale_x_date(name='Date',breaks = as.Date(ref$date[seq(length(ref$date)-54,length(ref$date),2)]), date_labels = "%d %b %y")+ggtitle("Weekly Price Changes (SPI-Domestic)")+scale_color_manual(name="",values = c("SPI_WoW"='darkblue',"SPI_YoY"='red'))+theme_gray()+theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0.8),panel.grid = element_blank(),legend.title = element_blank(),legend.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgrey"),panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))


``` 

```{r table1, echo=F }
x=SPI %>% 
  knitr::kable(
    format = "latex",
    align = "l",
    booktabs = TRUE,
    longtable = TRUE,
    linesep = "",
    col.names = NULL) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
      position = "center",
      latex_options = c("striped", "repeat_header"),
      stripe_color = "gray!15"
    )

```

\newfloatcommand{btabbox}{table}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{floatrow}
    \btabbox{%
```{r, fig.align="right", echo = F}
x
```
    }{\caption{Selected Commodities Showing Significant Change in Weekly Prices (percentage)}}
        \ffigbox{%
```{r, fig.align = "right", echo = F}
a
```
    }{}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
````

Following the comment below from @peter I have been able to make get graph and table in the same row but the alignment still looks a bit off. I have adjusted above code where I was able to get them side by side but it looks like table is smaller than the figure. I want my table to expand vertically to match the height of the graph or at least center align with the graph.
[image: I want the table to move a but upwards either by stretching or by shifting so that it aligns neatly with graph]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: do the answers to this question address your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659160/r-markdown-positioning-table-and-plot-side-by-side

Comment: @Peter thanks for the link. The first answer to the question is working for me but I need my table to align with the figure. I want my table to be shifted upwards in the document so that I looks neat

Comment: Could you make your question reproducible so that we could test and verify potential answers? This involves adding sample or actual data ideally by pasting the output from `dput(your_data)` into the question. These links provide some useful guidance; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, [MRE].

Comment: Added the sample data at the end. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is reproducible. Could you please check by copying the question into a fresh instance of R. Perhaps including an image of the resulting pdf in the question would be helpful to understand the short comings  of the current output.

Comment: changed the code in the question so that it becomes reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `\TopFloatBoxes` command in the figure environment. The `flowrow` package documentation gives more details and allows many more configurations.

````
\newfloatcommand{btabbox}{table}


\begin{figure}\TopFloatBoxes
  \begin{floatrow}
    \btabbox{%
```{r, fig.align="right", echo = F}
x
```
    }{\caption{Selected Commodities Showing Significant Change in Weekly Prices (percentage)}}
        \ffigbox{%
```{r, fig.align = "right", echo = F}
a
```
    }{}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
````

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks much better than before but in my output the header bar of the table is aligned with the heading of the graph and its not exactly like in your output. what could be the possible explanation for that.

Comment: Presumably if you work with the code in the question and answer you get the same result as in the answer? Without seeing your actual (minimal) code I'm not sure I could guess as to why. It might be worth reading up and exploring the options in the `floatrow` LaTeX package. I suspect there may be a clash between how rmarkdown/kable works with the figure environment and `floatrow`. It may need to be the subject of another question!

Comment: I change the `TopFloatBoxes` to `CenterFloatBoxes` and it aligned perfectly. there's just one another quick question: Why does it say TABLE 2 when there is no table in the output before this

Comment: I think the issue with captions relates to the property that kable includes a caption command. 
I suspect that in the initial code kable was silently generating a `NULL` caption 
followed by a second caption generated by the LaTeX caption command.
Moving the caption to the call to `kbl` coupled with including `\usepackage{caption}` in the yaml and removing the call to LaTeX caption gives the required caption numbering.

The default caption position for kable it on top of the table, I'm not sure this is what you are looking for. Placing captions on top of tables is the default location.