# Include figure labels in R markdown for side by side plots

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, subfigure

In my rmarkdown document, I want to include plots side by side to save space. For example, I want to include:

```
plot(rnorm(100))
hist(runif(100))
```

or

```
plot(rnorm(100))
hist(runif(100))
```

I don't really care if there is one caption for both subplots or one caption for each subplot. I just really want to include figures side by side and have some way to refer to them (Figure 1, etc). Does anyone have suggestions? I have this in my header:

header-includes:
- \usepackage{subfig}

When I don't have "fig.show='hold' " in my chunks, all of my captions work fine but my plots do not show up side by side. When I add fig.show='hold', the layout looks great but the captions disappear.

Comment: How about starting with `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` to make both plots appear in the same figure?  You'll probably want to modify the width so they don't get squeezed into the space of one figure.

Answer (score 5):

Adapting my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086985/7347699), you can combine cross-referencing by including the output format `bookdown::pdf_document2`". Note that I am manually appending the subfigure letter to the cross reference i.e. `\@ref(fig:fig-sub)a`:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{subfig}
---  

See Figures \@ref(fig:fig-sub)a and \@ref(fig:fig-sub)b

```{r fig-sub, echo = FALSE, fig.cap='two plots', fig.subcap=c('one plot', 'the other one'), out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.asp=1, fig.ncol = 2}
plot(1:10)
plot(rnorm(10), pch=19)
```
````

[image]