# Labeling imported subplots r-markdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

In my usecase, I import multiple pdf files (with plots in it). How do I label the subplots?

```
{r correaltionPlotRF, out.width="50%", fig.show='hold', echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Corrlation Plot"}
  # All defaults
  img1_path <- "./images/corrPlotA.pdf"
  img2_path <- "./images/corrPlotB.pdf"
  knitr::include_graphics(c(img1_path, img2_path))
```

If I improve code by addition of `fig.subcap=c('one plot', 'the other one')`

```
{r correaltionPlotRF, out.width="50%", fig.show='hold',fig.subcap=c('one plot', 'the other one'), echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Corrlation Plot"}
```

I get following error and does not compiles into updated pdf:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \subfloat
```

Expected Solution:

- Able to display labels (captions) for each plots
- Able to display main label (main caption)

***SOLUTION:***

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084140/include-figure-labels-in-r-markdown-for-side-by-side-plots?rq=2)